# How can I configure Blessed 1.9.5 with Python in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

```
...pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'blessed==1.9.5'     
distribution was not found and is required by awsebcli...
```

Message above appear when I type eb when I check if I installed awsebcli correctly.

How can I install the blessed 1.9.5 correctly so I can install awsebcli?
Please help..

Comment: Did you get any solution to your problem. We are facing this issue. Please post your solution

Comment: `pip install blessed`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, this worked for me

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/b/blessed/blessed-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue occur with the latest AWS CLI tool. I fixed it via MaxNoe's suggestion to run:

`pip install blessed`

I put this prior to my AWS CLI tool install command in my script. The script looks like:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-dev
python -m pip install -U pip
pip install blessed
pip install awsebcli
```