# elastic beanstalk, awsebcli, and blessed 1.9.5

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I was using the elastic beanstalk cli with AWS without any difficulty a few months ago. I wanted to update my website and ran into this error:

> me$ eb status Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/eb", line 5, in
>   
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 3095, in 
>       @_call_aside   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 3081, in _call_aside
>       f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
>       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 660, in _build_master
>       return cls._build_from_requirements(**requires**)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 673, in _build_from_requirements
>       dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 846, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'blessed==1.9.5' distribution
>   was not found and is required by awsebcli

I haven't been able to find anything about this error, except for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665282/how-can-i-configure-blessed-1-9-5-with-python-in-ubuntu)  about how to deal with a similar problem on ubuntu (I'm on a Mac) that has gone unanswered for a month.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

This is most likely caused by the fact that the `eb` script is using Apple's Python interpreter instead of the one you installed yourself.

There are two workarounds:

### 1. Run the EB CLI in a virtual environment

1. Create a virtual environment for the EB CLI by running `virtualenv ~/eb_cli_env`.
2. Run `source ~/eb_cli_env/bin/activate` to activate the created virtual environment.
3. Run `pip install awsebcli`.

After that, you should be able to use the `eb` command just fine. You will have to run `source ~/eb_cli_env/bin/activate` every time before you can use the EB CLI.

**--OR--**

### 2. Edit the shebang line in the `eb` script

1. Run `vim /usr/local/bin/eb`.
2. Change the first line from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

This will ensure the `eb` command works globally without using a virtual environment, however it is very likely that if you upgrade the `awsebcli` package you will have to edit the shebang line again.

Comment: So I actually did fix this but now don't remember how. My recollection is that the method I used for connecting with eb was discontinued in the last 6 months, and I just hadn't checked lately. If I remember what I did, I'll answer my question back here.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to install by brew on osx.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html#eb-cli3-install-osx

In my case I remove my previous installation by pip:

```
pip uninstall awsebcli
```

and run

```
brew install awsebcli
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/b/blessed/blessed-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

All I could find